# jQuery .Click event trigger goes beyond input element that it's assigned to

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, divi

I have this problem where an input `.remove-button` is not working as intended. When I click on the div(`.tag`) that contains `.remove-button` or around it, the `.remove-button` code will trigger, even though it was only set to it. Also for some reason, the code seems to be running multiple times deleting everything in the array

edit:
it seems to be triggering the click when I click anywhere inside the `#course-tag-container`.
`course_splice`.

script:

```js
//...
jQuery("input.remove-button").click((event)=>{
        //find course text
            course_inv.splice(        course_inv.indexOf(jQuery(event.target).closest(".tag").find(".course").text()), 1
                           );

              event.target.closest(".tag").remove();
        });   
//...
```

html for tag:

```html
  <div class="tag">
    <div class="course-wrap">
      <p class="course">LEED v4 Project Management</p>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input type="image" name="removeButton" 
        src="http://builtenvironmentplus.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/course_remove.svg" 
        alt="remove button" class="remove-button">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

screenshot of what it looks like:
[image: screenshot of what it looks like]

full script:

```html
<script>
    let course_inv = [];
  jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    
    //course field
    let course_field = document.getElementById("course-field");
    course_field.placeholder = "LEED v4 Project Management,LEED for Homes Workshop: Part2,...";
    
    jQuery(".wpcf7").wrap('<div id="form-container"/>');
    
    //add tag container
    jQuery(".wpcf7").before('<label class="tag-label">Selected Course<span style="font-size: 18px">(s)</span><span style="color:red;">*</span><div id="course-tag-container"/></label>');
     
    jQuery("#form-container").append('<button id="fake-submit" type="button">Send</button>');
    
    jQuery("#fake-submit").click((event)=>{
      
      jQuery("#course-field").val("");
      jQuery("#course-field").val(course_inv.join(", "));
      jQuery("#submit-button").click();
      
    })
    
});
  
    jQuery(document).on('ready ajaxComplete', function () {
    
    
    
    
        //add button functionality
    jQuery(".et_pb_post").wrap('<div class="course-wrapper" />');      
    jQuery(".et_pb_post").after('<input type="image" name="addButton" src="http://builtenvironmentplus.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/course_add.svg" width="100px" height="auto" alt="add button" class="add-button">');  
    jQuery(".add-button").wrap('<div/>');
    
    //adding button functionality   
    jQuery(".add-button").click((event)=>{    
        let course_name = jQuery(event.target).closest(".course-wrapper").find(".entry-title").text();
      
      if(course_inv.indexOf(course_name) === -1){
        
        course_inv.push(course_name);
        
        
       jQuery("#course-tag-container").append('<div class="tag"><div class="course-wrap"><p class="course">'+course_name+'</p><div class="input-wrapper"><input type="image" name="removeButton"    src="http://builtenvironmentplus.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/course_remove.svg" alt="remove button" class="remove-button"> </div></div></div>');
      
      jQuery("input.remove-button").click((event)=>{
                
        console.log("start------------\n"+"courses:" +course_inv.join(","));
        
        //find course text
        console.log( "index: "+course_inv.indexOf(jQuery(event.target).closest(".tag").find(".course").text()) );
        
            course_inv.splice(
                course_inv.indexOf(jQuery(event.target).closest(".tag").find(".course").text()), 1
                           );
        console.log("courses:" +course_inv.join(",")+"\n end----------------");
            
        
            event.target.closest(".tag").remove();
            
        });   
      }else{
        jQuery(".tag:contains('"+course_name+"')").addClass('animate')
          jQuery(".tag:contains('"+course_name+"')").on("animationend", ()=>{
            jQuery(".tag:contains('"+course_name+"')").removeClass('animate');
            });
      }
    })

    }); 
</script>
```

CSS:

```css
input,select{
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  padding-left: 20px !important;
  padding-right: 20px !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
}
ul input:nth-of-type(2){
  border:none;
}

.searchandfilter p
{
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: block !important;
}
.searchandfilter ul
{
    display: block !important;
}

.searchandfilter h4
{
    margin:20px 0;
    font-size:20px !important;
}
.widget-area .searchandfilter li, .widget-area .searchandfilter p
{
    display:block !important;
}

/*style the wp-pagenavi pagination links*/

.wp-pagenavi a,
.wp-pagenavi span {
    color: #000000;
    background: #f1f3f5;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    padding: 0.45em 0.8em !important;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all .5s;
}


/*style the wp-pagenavi current page number*/

.wp-pagenavi span.current {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background: #0070fc !important;
  font-size: 17px !important;
    border-radius: 100px;
}


/*style the wp-pagenavi pagination links on hover*/

.wp-pagenavi a:hover {
    color: #ffffff!important;
    background: #0070fc!important;
}


/*style the wp-pagenavi pages text*/

.wp-pagenavi .pages {
    background: none;
}


/*remove border and center the wp-pagenavi links*/

.wp-pagenavi {
    border-top: none;
    text-align: center;
}
/*contact form css*/
.wpcf7 {
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wpcf7-form{
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  
  padding: 0px;
  
}

#course-field{
  background-color: #deddbd;
  
}

.wpcf7-textarea {
  width: 100% !important;
  
}

.wpcf7 input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 43px;
  font-size: 17px !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 1px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  
}

.wpcf7 label{
  color: black !important;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.textarea{
  height: 150px !important;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  font-family: verdana !important;
  
}

#submit-button{
  background: #0078d3;
  border: 0px solid !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color 250ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: -10px !important;
}

#submit-button:hover {
  
  background-color: #3382BE;
}

.title{
  display: inline-block;
}

.color{
  background-color: #ededed !important;
}

.course-wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

.add-button{
  transition: transform 250ms;
    margin-top: 50%;
}
.add-button:hover{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background: url(black.png);
  filter: invert(15%) sepia(100%) saturate(7499%) hue-rotate(196deg) brightness(94%) contrast(102%);
}

#blog-container{
  left: 10px;
}

#fake-submit{
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    height: 44px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #005DA4;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 36px;
    transition: background-color 250ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -14px;
}

#fake-submit:hover{
  background-color: #3382BE;
}

/*css for the tags*/
.tag {
  background-color: rgb(220 220 220);
  display: inline-block;
  
    margin-bottom: 5px;

  border-radius: 25px;
    
}

.course{
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin:0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size:15px;
  margin-left:15px !important;
}

.input-wrapper{
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -15px
}

.remove-button{
  width:60px !important; 
  height:auto;
  margin-top:10% !important; 
  margin-bottom:0px !important;
}

.course-wrap{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom:-10px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}

#course-tag-container{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px !important;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border: #BBBBBB 1px solid;
    min-height: 43px;
    

}

#form-container{
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

#course-field, #submit-button{
  display: none;
}

.tag-label {
    color: black;
    font-size: 19px;
}

@keyframes highlight-tag {
  50%{
    background-color: #75ACD8;
  }
  100%{
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
  }
}
.animate{
  animation: highlight-tag 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: make a code pen or jsfiddle, its easy to see error

Comment: On the event you need to preventDefault and stop propagation The event.stopPropagation() method is an inbuilt method in jQuery which is used to stop the windows propagation. In the DOM tree when setting an event with the child element and the parent element as well then if you hit on the child element event it will call both child and the parent element as well. So with the help of this method this popup will not appear for the other element except selected element https://www.google.com.mx/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-event-stoppropagation-method/amp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the label all along!

In this line I wrap the entire container that's holding my tags with a label. This for some reason expands my iput to the entire label region.

```js
jQuery(".wpcf7").before('<label class="tag-label">Selected Course<span style="font-size: 18px">(s)</span><span style="color:red;">*</span><div id="course-tag-container"/></label>');
```

When changing the label to a paragraph and stopping it right before the div, it worked as intended.

```
jQuery(".wpcf7").before('<p class="tag-label">Selected Course<span style="font-size: 18px">(s)</span><span style="color:red;">*</span></p><div id="course-tag-container"/>');
```